# Auto setting a data model property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, setter

I am trying to set a data model property value based on a combination of two other property values within the same instance of a class. I want this to work automatically when the class is instantiated. However, if I were to use a constructor to do this, none of the other model properties would have been set at that point.

Then, whenever I try to access the property, `null` is returned. Any guidance on how to approach this scenario would be grateful.

**Model:**

I am trying to set `VersionSchemeCode` to have a value of a combination of both the `Version` AND the `Scheme.SchemeCode`. However, nothing is saved to the database.

```
public class SchemeVersion
{
    private string _VersionSchemeCode;

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Version { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int SchemeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SchemeId")]
    public virtual Scheme Scheme { get; set; }

    public string VersionSchemeCode
    {
        get
        {
            return _VersionSchemeCode;
        }
        set
        {
            using(var db = new MyDbContext())
            {
                var schemeCode = db.Schemes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.SchemeId == this.SchemeId).SchemeCode;

                _VersionSchemeCode = String.Format("{0}_V{1}", schemeCode, this.Version.ToString());
            }
        }
    }          
}
```

Comment: That setter is going to surprise users: it does not use the value being assigned. Remember the .NET guidelines: setters should appear to be close to just setting an underlying field, *and* should be quick. Ignoring the assigned value and accessing a database definitely misses.

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of points:

If `VersionSchemeCode` is calculated (as opposed to persisted) you could leave out the getter and just have the setter build the string based on the other property values.

Alternatively, you could use regular properties (with private backing fields) for `Version` and `Scheme` and update the `VersionSchemeCode` value any time they are set. So something like the following... (However, you need to be aware any time your `Version` or `Scheme` properties changes the `VersionSchemeCode` will be updated to reflect this.)

```
private int _version;

[Required]
public int Version 
{ 
   get 
   { 
      return _version; 
   }
   set; 
   { 
      _version = value; 
      VersionSchemeCode = String.Format("{0}{1}", Version, Scheme.SchemeCode);
   }
}
```

Finally, I don't particularly like including data access code in my POCO's. The POCOs should ideally be database and ORM agnostic. I would prefer to have some kind of `DataAccessService` with a `GetSchemeVersion` call. This could retrieve and hydrate your entity and then call some function to populate the calculated properties before returning it.

```
public SchemeVersion GetSchemeVersion(int id)
{
        using(var db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var entity = db.SchemesVersions.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
            entity.SetCalculatedValues();
            return entity;
        }         
}
```